# How can I use PrimeNG (rating) components in Ionic 4?

Tags: primeng, ionic4

some component like button and panel is working right but some other like rating and fielset not showing completely
i think it's because of missing font-awsome
you can see some rectangle insted of star icon:

[image]

```
npm install primeng --save
npm install primeicons --save
npm install @angular/animations --save
```

already added BrowserAnimationsModule to app.module
and this lines of code to angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  //...
],
```

added to import section of target page module:

```
import {PanelModule} from 'primeng/panel';
```

finlay in page.html:

```
<p-rating [(ngModel)]="val"></p-rating>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finlay i found the problem

first stop running ionic project. and then add primeng css after variable.scss and global.scss block like this:

```
"styles": [                           
      {
        "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"                
      },
      {
        "input": "src/global.scss"
      },
      "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
    ],
```